# divide the list of struts2 select into optgroup

Tags: java, struts2

I have Struts2 select tag with a list of names. I want to divide the list into struts optgroup tag

Somthing like below
cities

```
Top Cities  
   >Mumbai  
   >Delhi  
   >Banglore  
Other cities  
   >pune  
   >chandigrah  
   >hyderabad  
>...  
>..
```

I have below code , however unable to understand how to show values in optgroup only and not under select

```
<s:select name = "cityname" id = "cityname" list = "cityMap" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select a city"  
                 class="seloptionTxt" > 
                  <s:optgroup label="Top Bank" list = "cityMap" />
                  <s:optgroup label="Other Bank" list = "cityMap" />
-                   </s:select>
```

requesting suggestions

Comment: You're passing same value into the `list`. See example in https://struts.apache.org/docs/optgroup.html.

Comment: I wanted to divide my list in optgroup . Select will not have any entries apart from optgroup headers

Comment: Add empty value or use iterator tag with plain select / optgroup.

Comment: Yes added a empty list at select level

Comment: Thanks , it solved my problem

Comment: You can answer your question yourself and accept it to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating three different list

1. One empty list in select tag
2. Two list as per each optarg tags